# SSO - from java clients on windows to java server on linux

Tags: java, linux, single-sign-on

I have a java application running on windows, which I need to authenticate to java application (servlet container) running on linux. I'm unfamiliar of this issue, so tried googling and experminted with different technologies, here are some things I found - all weren't right for me:

1. Waffle - waffle works only for Windows server. I thought redirecting the incoming requests to a Windows server for the login process, but that just adds new servers which I will need to support.
2. Spengo - I doesn't say if it works linux, but I think it is meant for Windows server. (I mean this OS implementation - http://spnego.sourceforge.net/)

I'm using tomcat, but we are migrating to different servers, so I don't want a specific "tomcat" solution, but rather one that I can use in pure java, if possible (or a servlet filter solution, which can run on any standard serlvet container).

Comment: My communication is HTTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of patterns available. You haven't mentioned how is the communication between your Java application and the server.

You can easily get ServletFilter model to work if the communication between your applications and server is over http.

If the communication is over RMI, you can intercept RMI requests on the server and perform authentication/authorisation before completing the request.

Take a look at Spring security : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.html